# Trying to obtain context path using FacesContext getContextName() in backing bean returns null

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

I am trying to obtain the context path of my JSF based web application from a backing bean using the getContextName() method in following code, however the value returned is always null.

```
String contextPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContextName();
```

The backing bean is CDI managed @ViewScoped and the function containing above code is invoked from a JSF page. To rule out any of the other code in the function being the cause of the problem, I've moved this one line of code into its own function but the problem remains.

I've check that FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() is not null, so I'm at a loss as to why getContextName() returns null. I've also checked in the server log that there aren't any exceptions being thrown.

Is this correct way to obtain the context path in a backing bean? If so, any ideas why getContextName() returns null? If not, can you please suggest how I should obtain the context name please?

I am running Mojarra version 2.2.6 on GlassFish version 4.

**Update**

The content of the faces-config.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

The content on the web.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.validator.DISABLE_DEFAULT_BEAN_VALIDATOR</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_SCAN_PATHS</param-name>
        <param-value>/*.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_DISPATCH_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>FORWARD</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>facesExceptionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>facesExceptionFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/bug.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/viewExpired.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/http404.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I've created a new backing bean to reproduce the problem and at the same time rule out the other code in original backing bean. The code is

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestBacking implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void printContextPath() {
        String contextPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContextName();
        System.out.println("Context path: " + contextPath);
    }

}
```

Comment: It works for me here, and I've always used that approach. Can you post your web.xml, faces-config.xml and your ManagedBean code please?

Comment: @Evandro - I've just updated the question with the web.xml, faces-config.xml and the code. Out of interest in your code are you using JSF managed beans or CDI managed beans?

Comment: Yeah sorry I am using JSF Managed Beans (`@ManagedBean`). Can you try this `@Inject FacesContext facesContext;` (+getter/setter) and access like this `facesContext.getExternalContext()`?

Comment: @Evandro Just tried using @Inject FacesContext but when I deploy the app I get `CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [FacesContext] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField]`

Comment: I see I'm late to the party (just noticed the date)... But if  you can still recreate this you should show us how you are invoking `printContextPath()`.